# Why send a challenge with CHAP?

Tags: authentication, challenge-response

I have been reading about the Challenge-Handshake authentication Protocol (aka [CHAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol)).

Why send a challenge to the user and ask them to hash that challenge with the symmetric key and send that hash back to the server? Why not just ask for a hash value of a symmetric key? And what is the point of this protocol at all when you both have symmetric keys?

Comment: suggested an edit - if that is not the protocol you're referring to can you update your post to clarify what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-Handshake_Authentication_Protocol) points out a good reason for using a random challenge value: preventing replay attacks.

If the hash was always the same (as the hash of the symmetric key would be), then having listened in on one challenge-response cycle, a malicious listener could pass further handshake tests.